# laravel password confirm doesn't work

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I made sign up form, but there some are problems with passwords. i enter exactly the same passwords in password field and confirm password field but it fails

```
The password confirmation confirmation does not match.
```

my sign up form

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => '*Password']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '*Password Confirm']) !!}
</div>
```

my validations

```
'password' => 'required|between:8,255',
'password_confirmation' => 'confirmed',
```

i also try this

```
'password' => 'required|between:8,255',
'password_confirmation' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed',
```

and this

```
'password' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed',
 'password_confirmation' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed',
```

but still doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
 'password' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed'
```

Note the confirmed is added to password validation, you dont have to add the rules twice because a confirm field needs to have the same fields.

Answer (score 18):

This is best approach for password confirmation:

```
  'password' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed'
```

Explain:

confirmed: The field under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation.

For example, 
password field named: **password**

password confirmation field would be: **password_confirmation**

Then the confirmed property will add default check for password confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Your validation should be like :

```
'password'              => 'required | confirmed ',
'password_confirmation' => 'required ',
```

For more details [See Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-confirmed)

Answer (score 1):

`confirmed` must be passed into `password` validation rule:

```
'password' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed',
'password_confirmation' => 'required',
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laravel 5.2 
and I am able to work this out using

```
'password' => 'required|min:8|same:confirm_password'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Validator::extend('old_password', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                return Hash::check($value, current($parameters));
            },
                'Current password is wrong!'

            );
            $request->validate([
                'old_password'          => 'required|old_password:' . $user->password,
                'password'              => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
                'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
            ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$validator_password = validator::make($request->all(), [
            'old_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'old_password:' . $user->password],
            'new_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:new_password'
        ]);
```